# Newbie: Rails' way to query database in my case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using **Ruby v1.8** and **Rails v2.3**.

I have a two model objects: **Cars** and **Customers**,

Model **Cars**:

```
class car < ActiveRecord::Base

  #car has attribute :town_code

  has_many :customers

end
```

Model **Customers**:

```
class customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  # customer has attribute :first_name, :last_name
  belongs_to :car
end
```

Now in my controller, I got a string from VIEW, and the received string has the format **firstname.lastname@town_code**, for example a string like "**John.smith@ac01**" which can be parsed as `first_name="John"`, `last_name="smith"` and `town_code="ac01"`

Now I would like use the **Rails's way to query the database** to find all the customer objects (match the above conditions) from Customers table which has :

---

**first_name="John"**,

**last_name="smith"**

and owned a car(by car_id) with car's **town_code="ac01"**.

---

**what is Rails' syntax to query this?**

I know it should be something like (if I wanna count the nr of matched customer):

`Customer.count :consitions =>{:first_name => "John", :last_name=>"smith"...}`

**But, I am not sure how to refer to a customer that has a referenced car with car's** `town_code= "ac01"` **?**

**------------------   My question      --------------------**

I want to have **two queries**:

-one is used to count the number of matching customers,

-the other query returns the customers objects like `find_by_` query.

**What is the syntax in Ruby on Rails for the two queries?**

Answer (score 1):

It should be something similar to

```
Customer.where(:firstname => "John", :last_name => "Smith").count
```

If you have many Customers of Car, you can do something like

```
Car.where(...).customers.where(...)
```

You should really be firing `rails c` to test your queries in (I might be slightly off)

Comment: Your first query does not take into account the car association, which is the main part what I am asking for in my post. Your 2nd query seems fits my question, but I still need more information on the Rails sytax.

Comment: If it's Ruby 1.9 you can change that to `Customer.where(first_name: "John", last_name: "Smith").count`

Comment: I am using ruby 1.8.7 , what could be the syntax then?

Comment: @Mellon [Rails Guides: Active Record](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Comment: @Mellon What he posted is pre-1.9 syntax. Ruby 1.9 introduced an alternative to the `key => value` syntax by altering it to `key: value`

Comment: @Mellon And yes, his second line is what you're looking for, if Customers belong to a car then you find the car to get the customers associated with it, then query off those.

Comment: try running the 1st one in the console. it'll return the object. the object should have a reference to car. use `car.town_code` in your where string at the end of the first. you will need to do `:include => :car` in your where clause to include car's properties.

Comment: Can I use "Customer.all :joins => :cars, :conditions => {:first_name => "John", :last_name=>"smith", :cars => {:town_code => "ac01"}}"

Comment: You may need to do `Customer.all(:include => :car)...` just try it with `rails c`

Comment: @Joseph, why :include, shouldn't it be :joins ?

Comment: :include should nest the cars inside the customer, you should try both in the console.

Comment: Customers belong to a Car in his set up, wouldn't it be wiser to get the Car first with the :include on Customers?

Comment: Yes he should be able to retrieve a customer via car and vice versa.

Comment: I know that, I'm just thinking it'd be more efficient to grab the Parent object first and then operate on it's children (Car->Customer) instead of grabbing the Children and operating on the Parent (Customer->Car).

Comment: It would probably depend on which side would reduce the result set the most first, for speed. But you're right in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

You could have something like:

```
@customers = car.where(:town_code => town_code).customers.where(:first_name => first_name, :last_name => last_name)
```

And then just count the results:

```
@customer_count = @customers.count
```

This assuming you parsed your string into the variables `town_code`, `first_name`, and `last_name`, like you said.

**Edit**

I don't think Rails v2.3 supports these chains of Active Record queries because I believe it lacks lazy loading from DB. I'm not completely sure. Also, I realize my first suggestion would't work because there could be many cars with the same town_code. I guess you could solve it using the map function like so (not tested):

```
@customers = car.all(:conditions => {:town_code => town_code}).map{ |c| c.customers.where(:first_name => first_name, :last_name => last_name) }
```

And then count them like before:

```
@customer_count = @customers.count
```

Comment: I am using Ruby 1.8 not 1.9, can it be applied to Ruby 1.8? (and I am using Rails v2.3)

Comment: @Mellon I don't have those versions anymore, so I can't really try these out, but take a look at the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could do something like this: [source](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class)

```
Customer.find(:all, :include => :car, :conditions => "customers.first_name = 'John' AND customers.last_name = 'Smith' AND cars.town_code = 'ac01'")
```

Counting all customers with a specification can be achieved by this command: [source](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods/count)

```
Customer.count(:all, :include => :car, :conditions => "customers.first_name = 'John' AND customers.last_name = 'Smith' AND cars.town_code = 'ac01'")
```

By the way, if you are in the position to choose what you work with, I would advise you to go for Rails 3. The chaining methods described by Joseph would make this kind of query a lot easier and it'll save you upgrading issues down the road. (And you tagged the question for Rails 3)